Weakly compact sets forced to contain $0$
Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional real normed space and let $K\subset E$ be a weakly compact set such that, for each $\varphi\in E^*\setminus \{0\}$, there exists a unique $\tilde x\in K$ such that
$$\varphi(\tilde x)=\inf_{x\in K}\varphi(x)\leq 0\ .$$
Question: does $K$ necessarily contain $0$ ?

What about a circled centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$  ?

@an_ordinary_mathematician : The space must be infinite dimensional.

@IosifPinelis, Ok, I see in the embedding of the circle in an infinite dimensional space one might loose uniqueness of the minimizer.
